# is yahoo YQL public url server down?

Tags: yql

i was using https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/ url for getting liver cricket score ,is this server down?

can anyone help here please?

full url : https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20cricket.scorecard.live.summary&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2F0TxIGQMQbObzvU4Apia0V0&callback=

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about a service provided by a 3rd party, not programming

Comment: if anyone knows about it then please let me know otherwise i will automatically close it :)  this is question for yahoo support team only

YQL taged already

Comment: Expect to see more folks.  The docs page on the Yahoo Developer network has been updated to tell anyone with any questions on YQL to come here and use the #YQL hash tag.  Theyv'e closed the YQL developer forum, and the doc's are a fraction of what they used to be, not to mention half of all the YQL tables have been closed down, including the YQL console itself.  The end is nigh for YQL I fear.

Comment: This is now the official support page for YQL on the Yahoo Dev Network: https://developer.yahoo.com/support/yql/

Answer (score 0):

The service is being shut down as of Jan 3, 2019.

Not sure about alternatives.